# Animations- ViewAnimationUtils

Tags: android, animation

so iv recently started to look for places to learn more about animations in Android, and I got into this Android Development page:
https://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html#reveal

I tried making my own reveal effect, but I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol `ViewAnimationUtils`
```

My code:

```
RelativeLayout mlouta = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.louta);

int cx = (mlouta.getLeft() + mlouta.getRight()) / 2;
int cy = (mlouta.getTop() + mlouta.getBottom()) / 2;

int finalRadius = mlouta.getWidth();
ValueAnimator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(mlouta, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius); // error is : Cannot resolve symbol 'View AnimationUtils'
    anim.start();
```

When i tried importing `android.view.ViewAnimationUtils`, but same error...

[Error Screenshot](http://i.gyazo.com/d0933b15475ee117f5e8405a548e7818.png)

I am using Android Studio 0.8.9 (latest version).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the problem was my min sdk.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87380
Star this issue if you want ViewAnimationUtils to be backported into the Android Support Library.